# Don't create snapshot on stack deletion in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

How can I disable snapshot creation when I delete a CloudFormation stack?

I create an Aurora DB Cluster in my stack, and when I try to delete it I often get this error and I can't completely delete the stack:

> CREATE_FAILED AWS::RDS::DBClusterSnapshot Cannot create more than 100 manual snapshots

I don't want a snapshot at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `"DeletionPolicy" : "Delete"` for your RDSDBCluster resource in CFT.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html

Answer (score 2):

Set "DeletionPolicy" for "AWS::RDS::DBInstance":

```
DbInstance:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  DeletionPolicy: Delete
  Properties:
    Engine: aurora-postgresql
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html